# How to store contents of all paragraph as array elements in VBA without losing its formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to store ms word document paragraphs as array elements in VBA and display them in the end of document. My program is displaying values as text format only and removing all formattings like bold, italic and images.

I want to preserve the original paragraph formattings and display in bottom.I am trying since several hours but no success.

I want to do this by storing each paragraph as array elements.

Below is my code

```
Sub Data2Array()

    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    Dim insertPosition As Range
    Dim inputWord As Variant

    Total = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    MsgBox Total

    For I = 1 To Total

    Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(I).Range
        para.Select
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(I)
        MyArray(I) = Selection.Range
        MsgBox MyArray(I)

    Next I

     Set insertPosition = ActiveDocument.Range
     For Each inputWord In MyArray
        insertPosition.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        insertPosition = inputWord & vbCrLf
    Next


End Sub
```

Kindly guide how can I store paragraphs content with its complete formatting in array.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to find a different way to store the text to retain all formatting. Word's built-in AutoText/Building Blocks feature already does this. Or you could write formatted text to RTF files, then store the paths to those in an array.

Comment: Thank you for guidance. Unfortunately I am newbie in VBA, and I dont have knowledge of auotext/building blocks. Can you please provide any code, how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the functionality in the Word UI, first. Insert->Quick Parts is the starting point. That said, it's not clear why you'd need to duplicate all the paragraphs in the document at the end of the document? There might be a better way, but it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve...